# How to concatenate strings separated by dot in PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, expression

I would like to concatenate the string of field1 with field2 separated by dot and so on. However, when I put the `"."` the attribute values remain null. How to separate string by dot?

```
e = QgsExpression('concat((lpad("field1",2,0)),".",(lpad("field2",2,0)),".",(lpad("field3",3,0)),".",(lpad("field4",4,0)))')
```

Comment: Could you add an example of a starting situation and the desired output? Then, it is unclear what you mean with _the attribute values remain null_.

Comment: @mgri for example:
field1 = 1; field2 = 6; field3 = 15; field4 = 8. 
Desired output: 01.06.015.0008;

When I execute the _e_ function, no output is returned. However, if I execute this function in the field calculator the output will be generated as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some tests (and some fails) on this code snippet:

```
layer=iface.activeLayer() # load the layer as you want
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    e = QgsExpression('concat((lpad("field1",2,0)),".",(lpad("field2",2,0)),".",(lpad("field3",3,0)),".",(lpad("field4",4,0)))')
    value = e.evaluate()
```

before finding the solution, assuming that you are working on a layer with some fields (`"field1"`, `"field2"`, and so on).

Firstly, you can't call the fields in that way because they are not read correctly: writing `"field1"` as is doesn't provide its value but rather a string that stores the "field1" text. In fact, using the code snippet above with your expression would print:

```
print value
[f[.][f[.][fi[.][fie
```

which doesn't make any sense. So, the first step was slightly changing the sample code:

```
layer=iface.activeLayer() # load the layer as you want
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    expr = 'concat((lpad(%s,2,0)),".",(lpad(%s,2,0)),".",(lpad(%s,3,0)),".",(lpad(%s,4,0)))' %(feat["field1"], feat["field2"], feat["field3"], feat["field4"])
    e = QgsExpression(expr)
    value = e.evaluate()
```

I thought it would be enough, but printing the `value` variable gave me:

```
print value
01[.]06[.]015[.]0008
```

I solved the issue by using the `char()` function instead of `"."` (or `'.'`). The `char()` function, available from the Field Calculator, returns the character associated with a Unicode code. For the (full stop) dot, the Unicode code is 46 (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Basic_Latin) Wikipedia page for reference). This was the final code:

```
layer=iface.activeLayer() # load the layer as you want
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    expr = 'concat((lpad(%s,2,0)),char(46),(lpad(%s,2,0)),char(46),(lpad(%s,3,0)),char(46),(lpad(%s,4,0)))' %(feat["field1"], feat["field2"], feat["field3"], feat["field4"])
    e = QgsExpression(expr)
    value = e.evaluate()
```

which printed the expected result:

```
print value
01.06.015.0008
```

---

**Bonus** If you want to store the result in a new field (e.g. `"field5"`), adding these lines to the last code should be enough for updating it:

```
layer=iface.activeLayer() # load the layer as you want
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    expr = 'concat((lpad(%s,2,0)),char(46),(lpad(%s,2,0)),char(46),(lpad(%s,3,0)),char(46),(lpad(%s,4,0)))' %(feat["field1"], feat["field2"], feat["field3"], feat["field4"])
    e = QgsExpression(expr)
    value = e.evaluate()
    with edit(layer):
        feat["field5"] = value
        layer.updateFeature(feat)
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings in expressions need to be wrapped in single quotation marks, i.e.

```
concat((lpad("field1",2,0)),'.',
       (lpad("field2",2,0)),'.',
       (lpad("field3",3,0)),'.',
       (lpad("field4",4,0)))
```

Comment: Did not work. Because the _concat_ function must be wrapped in single quotation marks, otherwise _concat_ is considered as variable. When I put _concat_ wrapped by single quotation marks, gives syntax error in the dot ( _'.'_)